# Android : Difference between Component and Widget?

Tags: android

what is the difference between Component and Widget? in the Android UI Design Level. Difference between Java Class Creative UI and using .xml layout file design?

Answer (score 1):

"widget" for subclasses of View that have a visual representation to the user by default -- things like TextView, Button, ListView, etc.

I tend to use the term "view" for something that could be any subclass of View, including pure containers like LinearLayout.

But, again, there is no particular harm in referring to them by either term.